# Honoree section not appearing on contribution page even though enabled

Tags: drupal, contributions, contribution-page, honoree

I have a website on Drupal 7 that is using the latest version of CiviCRM (5.13.4).

I'm trying to set up a contribution page with an honoree section. The options appear when setting up the contribution page and I have set the section as enabled without issue but when viewing the page, the section where a user should be able to enter the honoree information isn't appearing.

I have checked for errors, turned on debugging, etc and nothing relevant has appeared so there aren't any clues as to why it isn't appearing on the front end.

I've scoured the internet but I can't seem to find much help so hopefully someone here will be able to make sense of what might be happening.

Any advice / help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: 
I can see in the source code there is the JavaScript for the honoree section but that is all. The console gives no errors as to why it isn't appearing.

Comment: Can you replicate the issue on the demo site (https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org)?  It would be good to see if the problem is specific to your site, or happens with your configuration on any site.

Comment: You might want to try switching theme to eg Garland in case the theme is affecting things

Comment: @petednz-fuzion I can confirm it isn't the theme. I switched it to Garland and it still didn't show

Comment: @JonG-MegaphoneTech The honoree section appears to work on the demo site but it's a little difficult to replicate the full configuration with the files and database possibly being set up differently. I'm concerned that whoever added in the option did it wrong but I'm not sure how I would check that. As I understand, you need to add columns and options into the database before you can enable it. Forgive me, this is rather uncharted territory for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of frustration, I found a custom template that the donation page was using with some JavaScript that was supposed to show the honoree section when it was enabled.

This was created a few years ago and evidently no longer worked.

Disabling this template allowed the honoree section to come through and show on the donation page.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely to be a JavaScript error.  [Check for console errors](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/tools/debugging/#troubleshooting-tools); if you have errors but it's not obvious how to resolve them, edit your question to include the errors (as text, not screenshots please).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but there are no console errors. I turned on debugging, etc but there's no clues! I can see the JS in the source code but nothing else.